# Revit Groups vs OST_IOSDetailGroups

Tags: api, revit

Can someone help me understand the difference?

Why does i = 2887 while ii = 3008

```
FilteredElementCollector groupInstances = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(Group));
FilteredElementCollector groupInstances1 = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_IOSDetailGroups);
FilteredElementCollector groupInstances2 = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_IOSModelGroups);

int i = groupInstances.Count(); // = 2997
int ii = groupInstances1.Count(); // = 3008
int iii = groupInstances2.Count(); // = 155
```

---

Possibly answering my own question here, but `OST_IOSDetailGroups apears` to include `GroupTypes` in addition to Groups. Of course this lead to another question...  Why does Revit expose a method for obtaining Groups, but only detail groups?  Why isn't the same functionality available for Model Groups?  And ultimately, **how do I get started separating the model Groups from the model GroupTypes?**

Follow up... This seems to do the trick, but isn't very elegant.  I'm sure there is a better way.

```
try
{
   GroupTypeId = group.GetTypeId().ToString();
} 
catch
{
    GroupTypeId = "GroupType";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all Revit categories include the instance elements as well as their types.

The `Walls` category includes all `Wall` instances as well as all `WallType` elements.

The `Windows` category includes all window family instances as well as all window family symbols.

And so on...

Why do you expect groups to behave differently?